# Trigger Click Event in Bing Maps

Tags: jquery, bing-maps

I'm having a bit of trouble with the click event on Bing Maps.
I've got an array of stores and I can put all the pin and click events (to open a infobox) with no problems

```
var STORES = [
    {
        id: 123,
        lat: 1.23456789,
        lng: -1.23456789,
        name: 'AEVA'
    },
    ...
]

for (var i = 0; i < STORES.length; i++) {
    var pinOptions: {icon: 'map-pin.png?id'+STORES[i].id, width: 29, height: 52},
        LatLng = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(STORES[i].lat, STORES[i].lng),
        pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(LatLng, pinOptions);

    pin.content = '<p>'+STORES[i].name+'</p>';

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);

    bing.pinLayer.push(pin);
}
```

Now the problem is, when the user arrives at the page through the search page, wich basically adds an hashtag with the id, for example /stores#id123

I want the map to open automatically the box with that id, so I've added this code

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.replace("#", "");
if(hash.length>0){
    var pin = $('img[src*="?'+hash+'"]').parent();
    pin.trigger('click');
}
```

But it just won't work. I've also tried

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.invoke(a, 'click');
```

But nothing happened, does anyone have any solution, to trigger the event click?

Thanks

Comment: is it intended that the hash is /storesid123?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "it just won't work"? could you be more descriptive or like what errors are popping up?

Comment: When I said "It just won't work" I meant the "trigger('click')" won't run the event that opens the box "Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);"

Comment: The problem is not the hash, is the event handler that bing uses. I can't access it (don't know how to trigger it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Microsoft.Maps.Events.invoke` function expects *entity object* and not Html element. An Entity can be any one of the following types: [Infobox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675208.aspx), [Polygon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427594.aspx), [Polyline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427597.aspx), [Pushpin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427597.aspx), [TileLayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427598.aspx), or [EntityCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427616.aspx).

Having said that you could consider the following approach for finding [Pushpin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427597.aspx):

```
function findPin(map,storeId)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < map.entities.getLength();i++){
        var entity = map.entities.get(i);
        if(entity.getIcon === undefined) continue;
        var icon = entity.getIcon();  
        if(entity.getIcon() === "map-pin.png?id" + storeId) return entity;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var storeId = window.location.hash.replace("#id", "");
if(storeId.length > 0){
    var selectedPin = findPin(bing,storeId);
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.invoke(selectedPin, 'click');
}
```

where

```
function displayInfobox(e) {
    infobox.setLocation(this.target.getLocation());
    infobox.setOptions({ visible: true });
}
```

Comment: This is correct. I had this same issue when I was creating a Bing Maps heat map application last year and this was how I solved the problem.

Comment: I had to tweak it a little bit but it worked, thanks

Comment: I had an issue when attempting to use e.target where target was undefined. Using 'this' solved my problem. Thanks for the good sample.